# Using Timber for WordPress admin screens

Tags: wordpress, timber, wordpress-admin

I am building a WordPress plugin to show documentation related to the project. There is a good amount of HTML required in the views, with the content coming from markdown files.

I was wondering if it's at all possible to use [Timber Plugin](https://www.upstatement.com/timber/) for admin screens, to help keep everything clean? I cannot find anything in the docs.

I have a function that renders a view (called by `add_menu_page()`) which is working fine. If I `echo` some text or HTML or even echo the contents of a file, I see what I'd expect.

Attempting to use Timber in the same way as I would in a theme, like this:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
Timber::render(plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ) . 'views/docs.twig', $context);
```

This just gives me an empty page, with no errors thrown at all.

Do I need to initialise Timber in some way first?

This is the first plugin I have made and my PHP isn't brilliant so apologies if this question isn't easy to follow or understand.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Template Locations](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/template-locations/#nav) documentation, by default Timber looks in the `views/` directory of the current theme for the template files. You can add other paths this way:

```
Timber\Timber::$locations = array(
    plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'views/'
);
```

Timber will look in that location first, so templates in the plugin will override any in the theme if they share the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Just figured it out.

So, on your `functions.php`, do the usual procedure of adding a page on the admin side

prepare the function:

```
function documents_menu() {
  add_menu_page('Docs', 'Docs', 'manage_options', '', 'myplguin_admin_page', 'dashicons-heart', 6);
}
```

then the hook:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'documents_menu' );
```

then the renderer function:

```
function myplguin_admin_page(){
    if ( ! class_exists( 'Timber' ) ) {
        // if you want to show some error message, this is the right place
        echo "Timber doesn't exist!";
        return;`enter code here`
}
```

here's the key part:

```
Timber::render( 'docs.html.twig', array(
    'args' => $args,
    'instance' => $instance,
    /* any other arguments */
    ));
}
```

then on your `[theme]/views`, create `docs.html.twig` and create your twig file!